# Pepperからurllib2でのhttp通信エラーの対処方法

Tags: python, pepper

Pepperからurllib2でHTTP通信を行っていますが、`NAOqi OS 2.4.3` から `2.5.5`にOSのバージョンをあげたところ

```
 [Errno 1] _ssl.c:507: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure>
```

のエラーが出力されるようになりました。

requestsでのHTTP通信でも試してみましたが、

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: [Errno 1] _ssl.c:504: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

と似たようなエラーとなりました。

リクエストURLは「https://api.apigw.smt.docomo.ne.jp/dialogue/v1/dialogue」です。

対処方法はありますでしょうか。

NAOqi 2.5.5
Python 2.7.6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 2.7.6 が古すぎるのが問題なのでしょう。
Python 2.7.13 では問題ありませんが、Python 2.7.6 では再現しますね。

requestsのインストールを以下のようにしてみてください。

```
pip install requests[security]
```

OpenSSLラッパーの pyOpenSSL と、必要なライブラリが一通りインストールされます。この状態でいちおう再現しなくなりました。

これで駄目ならOpenSSLのバージョンを確認するべきかと思います。

Comment: 「再現」は別のOSでも再現するという意味です

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。ただPepperのNAOqiOSではpipコマンドが使用できないため上記のコマンドを実行できませんでした。
別方法でGit上にある最新のrequestsを適用することにしましたが、こちらでもエラーが出力されました。
cannot import name utils
方法:[https://developer.softbankrobotics.com/Software/documentation/%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%83%95%E3%82%99%E3%83%A9%E3%83%AA%E3%81%AE%E5%88%A9%E7%94%A8%E3%81%AB%E3%81%A4%E3%81%84%E3%81%A6_v1.0.0.pdf]

Comment: ダメ元で書きますが、 pip install requests[security] はpyOpenSSL、cryptography、idna を依存元としてインストールするオプションです。依存ライブラリを全て手動で展開していってみるぐらいしか試せる手はないと思います。 https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyOpenSSL https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cryptography https://pypi.python.org/pypi/idna https://pypi.python.org/pypi/six これらを全部展開して動けば儲けもの程度の話かと思いました